# How to search a string including a single quote by using SQL WHERE clause

Tags: java, android, sql

I want to search a string which including a single quote by using SQL WHERE clause. For example, I want to search "Tom's house" and the SQL clause should be "location = 'Tom's house'". Can anybody help me to format the SQL clause?

Comment: Somebody please explain this guy how to use parametrized queries

Comment: @T.J.: Trust me, I would, if I knew any Java or Android.

Answer (score 7):

If you're doing the query literally, you can double up the `'` so it's `Tom''s house` as SQLMenance said.

The better general solution, though, is to use *parameterized queries* via [`java.sql.PreparedStatement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), e.g.:

```
PreparedStatement ps;
ResultSet rs;

// Create the prepared statement
ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT x FROM table WHERE location = '?'");

// Set the parameter -- we don't have to quote it, the SQL classes do that
ps.setString(1, "Tom's House");

// Do it
rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Not only does this solve the quoting problem for you, but more importantly it helps protect you from [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection) attacks on your database. **Never** include any user-supplied data "as is" in a query via string concatenation or the like, either use parameterized queries or make *absolutely sure* you're escaping the data correctly beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

double the single quote  `Tom''s house`

Comment: If you do not have full control over what will be put in place of `Tom's House`, you better use TJ's method. It is possible for someone to put `\'` and then control the rest of the statement in the powerful language of SQL, which could possibly give the hacker access to other data, depending on the statement. That is why manual escapes are not good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of prepared statement API avoids such issues.